# Applying a series of functions to text nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to apply a series of functions to text nodes.
At present, it looks like such:

```
<xsl:function name="local:enhanceTypo" as="text()">
  <xsl:param name="s"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="

    replace(
      replace(
        translate($s,'&lt;&gt;','‹›')
        ,'a.a.O.','a.&#x2006;a.&#x2006;O.'
      )
      ,'z.B.','z.&#x2006;B.')
  "/>
</xsl:function>
```

There is a lot more to be done in `local:enhanceTypo` and it seems to be funny to make this as a series of nested function calls.

Is there a simple-to-read and -understand way in XSLT2 to sequentially apply a lot of functions to my string?

Comment: this would look like `<xsl:variable name="s005" select="replace($s004,'x','y')"/>` with a potentially large set of variables $sXXX? Well, this works - thanks for the idea. But is this an efficient way to apply those functions?

Comment: I don't know and have no way of knowing - other than testing specific formulations against a specific processor. In general, having a readable (and therefore maintainable) code is worth a couple of microseconds; if it proves *too* slow - AND if nesting proves *significantly* faster (which is not at all certain) - then use nesting and use white-space characters and comments to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly chaining variables is one way. I often reuse the same variable name when doing this:

```
<xsl:variable name="v" select="replace($v, ....)"/>
<xsl:variable name="v" select="replace($v, ....)"/>
<xsl:variable name="v" select="replace($v, ....)"/>
```

because it's then easy to see what's going on, and to add extra calls into the sequence. I can't speak for other processors, but in Saxon when you do this, the variables are automatically inlined, so it's exactly as if you wrote the deeply nested function call, just easier to read.

If you're into higher-order functions, then with 3.0 there's another way. You can define a sequence of functions like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="replacements" select="
  replace(?, "a", "A"),
  replace(?, "b", "B"),
  replace(?, "c", "C")"/>
```

and then you can do a fold-left operation over this sequence:

```
fold-left($replacements, $string, function ( $in, $f ) { $f($in) })
```

If your original and replacement strings are in two xs:string* variables $in and $out, then you could instead define the sequence of functions as

```
<xsl:variable name="replacements" select="
  for-each-pair($in, $out, function($i, $o){ replace(?, $i, $o) })"/>
```

That is, for each pair of input and output strings you create a function that replaces this input by this output, and then you apply the sequence of functions using fold-left.

Fun, eh?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the possibility to re-use a variable - I didn't realize that before. fold-left seems to do too much fun at present. However it's useful to know about it - thank you, again.